# Check textarea text for required words

Tags: jquery, validation, cpu-word

So, I'm working on a writer panel, where I have limited the maximum and minimum number of words in a textarea. The next thing I would like to do is to make sure it checks if the writer has used all the required words (keywords) in the text.
For example
The required keywords for the text is: word1, word2, word3

i want something to check the text and make sure these words have been used before adding it into the database.
i've been searching for a solution like this for hours, but non of the examples i found really covers my needs.

any help appreciated,
regards,
Tamas

Comment: Check this thread: Might be your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418034/jquery-searching-textarea-value-for-words-using-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a datasource such as an array to store the required words you could check your input for the values required.

Consider the following:

```
var requiredWords = ['hello','javascript','array'];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkEssay').bind('click',function(){
       enteredText = $('#essay').val();
        $(requiredWords).each(function(){
            if(enteredText.indexOf(this) == -1){
                alert(this + ' not found!');   
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

I have made a small mock up of this functionality here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pSg4z/)

---

Edit:

I have added functionality for different word cases : [JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/pSg4z/1/)

Comment: works like charm. the only thing I'm on now is to make the submit button actually submit after all words have been found! thanks for the reply and help!

Comment: sure :) could you also please help me get the submit actually work if all the words are found?;)

Comment: of course, i need a bit more detail though - server side processing, ajax details? append your original post if you will.

Comment: oh, one more thing...what should I do, to make it accept proper case words, lowercase and uppercase words as well? now, when I add a word, with a big letter, it won't accept it...also, the submit button will lead to a page called add.php, where the rest of the script will be executed. thanks

Comment: added the modification in an edit, cant really comment on submitting to your page perhaps if you share some of your existing code i can help you out - my first guess would be at something like http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: awesome! works like charm! thanks a lot! actually, there's no code added yet, since I'm working on the frontend panel atm. what I actually want is a simple submit button with this word checker included. so a basic <input type="button" id="checkEssay" value="Submit"/> -> if all words are used, it should work as normal... with something like <form method="POST" action="add.php"> ...adding this in front of the form does nothing :S

Comment: The `<input>` should be of `type="submit"` if i'm not mistaken ;) adding `event.preventDefault()` when all the words arent found will prohibit the submission.

Comment: right :) thanks a lot ;) well, i have found yet another bug..what if I'm using multiple words as keywords ?! example var requiredWords = ['word one', 'test word two']; it won't accept "test Word two" for example...is there a way to bypass this? sometimes i need to use three words as one keyword... thanks in advance!

Comment: it works with spaces ie. multiple words as one "word"; just tested ;)

Comment: weird, here's the example page... zerovic.com/webcams/writer/index.html - for some reason, it won't work if I play around with the uppercase formats...for example, it won't accept "cam With her" or "hot Cam girls"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pSg4z/2/ - should solve all your issues. regardless of case anywhere ;)

Comment: awesomeness! ;) thanks a lot! works like charm :) the thing you said before, regarding to the "event.preventDefault()" where should i add that to make it actually submit if no errors were found?

Comment: im currently trying to make it work with this code `code`
<script type="text/javascript">

var requiredWords = ['Shanelle', 'Cam With Her', 'Hot Cam Girls'];


$(document).ready(function(){
var ok = true;
$('#checkEssay').bind('click',function(){
enteredText = $('#minMaxWord').val();
$(requiredWords).each(function(){
if(enteredText.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.toUpperCase()) == -1){
alert('Keyword ' + this + ' not found!');
ok = false;
}
});
});

$("form.test").submit(function() {
if (ok) {
return true;
}
return false;
});

});
`code` it won't do anything if i leave / check then add the keyword

Comment: so, basically what happens is, that if I add a text with all the added keywords, it works with no problem. when I leave one keyword, then press submit, it brings up the alert, which is ok as well. but after, when I add the missing keyword and press submit again, nothing happens :S

Comment: now, when a keyword is missing, the alert comes up, but it still goes forward to the add.php check plz zerovic.com/webcams/writer/ - same happens on the jsfiddle website, when you leave a keyword..

Comment: still no luck...2 bugs I'm facing with. 1) the script won't go forward once I add the missing keywords - after the first check and first alert 2) the script goes forward even if the keyword is missing after giving the alert -> http://jsfiddle.net/wbxEW/